# vue-router does not go to other paths

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

So when I am on the home page the (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) I am getting the right component that I have set to it in the vue-router file but whenever I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard it is showing me a 404 error and I really do not know why. The path of the component is right

**This is my vue-router file:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import loginPage from '../Pages/loginPage'
import dashboard from '../Pages/dashboard'

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'login',
            component: loginPage
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: dashboard,
        },
    ],
});

export default router;
```

**This is my app.js file**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import index from './Index.vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
import router from './router';

import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';

window.Vue = require('vue').default;


new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(index),
  }).$mount('#app')
```

**And this is the index,vue file (where I am showing the components whenever the link changes)**

```
<template>
    <div class="aa">
        <p>hallo world</p>
        <router-view/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component hoi.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: [Have you configured your server properly?](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using laravel vue, you must check that you pass route

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
  return view('welcome');
})->where('any','.*')->name('vue')
```